# stop bootstrap date-picker selecting today date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I've got a bootstrap date picker on my ruby on rails application but it keeps selecting today date as default how do I stop this?

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(".datepicker").attr('readOnly', 'true').css("background-color","white");
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        "setDate": new Date(-70),
         yearRange : '-70:-19',
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         autoclose: true});
      });
</script>
```

As shown below today's date 30th march is selected. If the user doesn't change the year or month all dates for march in initial view will select for 
"day March 2018"

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a bootstrap datePicker this is jquery datePicker, see the below for bootstrap datePicker, for bootstrap datePicker you can use bootstrap datePicker gem, try to the following added to `todayHighlight: false`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateInput = $('input[name="date"]'); // Our date input has the name "date"
  var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : 'body';
  dateInput.datepicker({
    "setDate": new Date(-70),
         yearRange : '-70:-19',
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         todayHighlight: false,
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         autoclose: true
  });

  $('#date').datepicker('setStartDate'); // <-- SO DOES THIS
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bootstrap-iso">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```